# internal server error with htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I'm trying to take a URL with multiple querystring parameters into a folder structure URL and am getting a 500 internal server error.

My incoming URL looks like 
`www.fivestarprofessional.com/ag?PY=16&PF=wm&MKT=Delaware`

My destination URL I need written as
`delaware.fivestarprofessional.com/16/wm/index.html`

I created 3 `RewriteCond` statements to capture the parameters and a RewriteRule to create the output

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(PY=.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(PF=.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(MKT=.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule %3.fivestarprofessional.com/%1/%2/index.html
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: see what the logs have to say

Comment: Your rule is broken and full of syntex errors. where did you get it from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
RewriteCond "%{QUERY_STRING}" "^PY=([^&]+).*&PF=([^&]+).*&MKT=([^&]+)" [NC]
RewriteRule "www.fivestarprofessional.com/ag" "%3.fivestarprofessional.com/%1/%2/index.html"
```

The following issues have been corrected:

- `RewriteRule` takes 3 arguments instead of 2.
- Arguments to `RewriteCond` hadn't been enclosed in quotes.
- The backreferences into the `RewriteCond` rules ...

  - ... only refer to the last condition matched (pointed out by @anubhava, being documented in the apache httpd docs). Therefore, the rules need to be collapsed in one.
  - ... referred to the parameter name plus the complete remainder of the query string
  - ... would have matched against query string starting with the respective ul parameter due to the use of the `^` anchor.
  - ... would have been empty anyway, as the rules fired when the patterns did not match ( use of `!` prefix )

Recommended reading is the proper section of the [apache httpd documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

The solution as it stands assumes that...

- the query string starts with the url parameter `PY`
- the order in which the url parameters `PY`, `PF`, `MKT` appear in the query string is fixed.

Comment: After appending the [R=301,L] the rewrite rule is now working

Comment: full string:  RewriteCond "%{QUERY_STRING}" "^PY=([^&]+).*&PF=([^&]+).*&MKT=([^&]+)" [NC]
RewriteRule "/ag" "http://%3.fivestarprofessional.com/%1/%2/index.html" [R=301,L]

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule for your redirection:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)PY=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteCond %1::%{QUERY_STRING} (.*?)::(?:|.*&)PF=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteCond %1/%2::%{QUERY_STRING} (.*?)::(?:|.*&)MKT=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^ag/?$ http://%2.fivestarprofessional.com/%1/index.html? [L,NC,NE,R=302]
```

`%` variables are captured only from the most recent condition using same `%{QUERY_STRING}`

Comment: is it not possible to match the whole query string in 1 RewriteCond ?:)

Comment: If requirement is that query parameters can appear in any order then it is not possible to match+capture them in single `RewriteCond`

Comment: I'm testing it out now,  i believe i have another conflict in my htaccess file that is stripping out the parameters as i'm getting redirected to my homepage.

Comment: You should post your .htaccess in question